# Issue Passing list of custom object from lightning component to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am having real issues passing a list of my Transaction__c object from my lightning controller into my apex controller my transactions apex:attribute is like so:

```
<aura:attribute name="transactions" type="Transaction__c[]"/>
```

And my lightning controller method is:

```
addTransactions : function(component, event) {
//var transactionList = component.get("v.transactions");
var action = component.get("c.insertTransactions");
    action.setParams({
        tList : component.get("v.transactions")
    })
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            alert("From Server: " + response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else{
            console.log('ERROR:' + state + response.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
}
```

And my apex controller method is:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Transaction__c> insertTransactions(List<Transaction__c> tList) {
    try{
    insert tList;
    }
    catch(exception e){
        System.debug('error inserting transactions @ ' + e);
    }
return tList;
}
```

In the console log the error I am recieving is:

> ERROR = message: Unable to read sObject

[image]

Is there a specific way to pass lists because I must be missing something.

An example of the array that would be passed looks like this in the console:

[image]

Comment: @Nebbyyy I didn't realize you'd tagged this as [tag:apex], so this was automatically closed, but the question I linked would appear to solve your issue. Please let us know if that's not the case, and we'll be glad to reopen your question once you **[edit]** it to provide additional information.

Comment: Did you check that the running user has read access to `Transaction__c`?

Comment: Yeah user has system admin

Comment: Maybe the Duplicate Mark(or question) for this should be removed - they both are different !?